# How to update multi-label classification prediction with extra information on the probability of a label occurring, given the other labels

Tags: bayesian, multilabel

I think this question is best expressed directly with an example.

Let us say I have a picture of a dog in a lease in the park, and an algorithm for object recognition splits the following labels with the corresponding probabilities: ‘dog’:0.8, ‘grass’ = 0.9, ‘dolphin’ = 0.8.

My dog happens to look like a dolphin, so the algorithm is confused.
Now, I do know that the probability of seeing a dolphin in an environment with grass is very unlikely, so let us say $p(\text{Dolphin}|\text{Grass})=0$.

Let me assume that the algorithm was only trained with images with single objects, so it never had the opportunity to learn these relationships. I, however, have a list of these conditional probabilities among labels, and I would like to exploit these to post-process the predictions of the algorithm and improve them. In this case, it seems obvious that, given that there is a good chance there is grass in the picture, the probability of finding a dolphin in the picture should be updated and set to almost zero.

I wonder how can this be done in a mathematically correct way? My suspicion is that I should interpret the output of the network as a series of values $p(\text{label}_i)$, and then I should use the conditional probabilities to build the joint probabilities of all the possible combinations of labels. I appreciate opinions on this! Thank you!